# Android: Two Views On Top of Each Other Using XML

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, view, android-linearlayout

I want to display two views on a screen.  One is a randomly positioned dot bitmaps. I can get that do display with setContentView(...).
I also have two bitmaps and a textview that are arranged via xml layout language and then using setContentView(R.layout.activity_title);

---

**DrawV.java**
!!!BASICALLY I THINK I HAVE TWO setContentViews(...) THAT I WANT TO DISPLAY AT THE SAME TIME.  TELL ME IF YOU WANT MORE INFORMATION.

---

public class DrawV extends View {
    VARIABES...

public DrawV(Context context) {
    CREATE CIRCLES (CIRCLE OBJECTS) STORING COORDINATES RANDOMLY CHOSEN...

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    DRAW THESE CIRCLES AS BITMAPS...SCREEN IS NOW RANDOMLY COVERED WITH MANY DOTS
}

---

**GameActivity.java**

---

public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawV drawView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    drawView = new DrawV(this);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_title);    !!!SHOWS LAYOUT (HOPEFULLY TEXTVIEW, TWO BUTTONS, AND RANDOMLY POSITIONED DOTS (DOTS NEVER WORKS) WHICH IS OVERDONE BY DRAWVIEW...
     setContentView(drawView); !!!IF THIS STATEMENT IS SECOND IT RENDERS INTEAD OF THE PREVIOUS STATEMENT.  OTHERWISE activity_title shows.
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    DEFAULT CODE...
}
```

}

!!!THE WORST OFFENDER: activity_title.xml

---

**activity_title.xml**

---

!!!I AM NOT SURE HOW TO WRITE THIS. IT DOESN'T CURRENTLY WORK.
I want to display two views on a screen.  One is a randomly positioned dot bitmaps. I can get that do display with setContentView(...).
I also have two bitmaps and a textview that are arranged via xml layout language and then using setContentView(R.layout.controls...);

---

DrawV.java
!!!BASICALLY I THINK I HAVE TWO setContentViews(...) THAT I WANT TO DISPLAY AT THE SAME TIME.  TELL ME IF YOU WANT MORE INFORMATION.

---

public class DrawV extends View {
    VARIABES...

public DrawV(Context context) {
    CREATE CIRCLES (CIRCLE OBJECTS) STORING COORDINATES RANDOMLY CHOSEN...

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    DRAW THESE CIRCLES AS BITMAPS...SCREEN IS NOW RANDOMLY COVERED WITH MANY DOTS
}

---

GameActivity.java  !!!STARTING .JAVA

---

public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawV drawView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    drawView = new DrawV(this);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_title);    !!!SHOWS LAYOUT (HOPEFULLY TEXTVIEW, TWO BUTTONS, AND RANDOMLY POSITIONED DOTS (DOTS NEVER WORKS) WHICH IS OVERDONE BY DRAWVIEW...
     setContentView(drawView); !!!IF THIS STATEMENT IS SECOND IT RENDERS INTEAD OF THE PREVIOUS STATEMENT.  OTHERWISE activity_title shows.
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    DEFAULT CODE...
}
```

}

!!!THE WORST OFFENDER: activity_title.xml

---

activity_title.xml

---

```
!!!I AM NOT SURE HOW TO WRITE THIS. IT DOESN'T CURRENTLY WORK.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >
                <TextView
                android:textColor="#ff0000"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:text="@string/timer"
                android:id="@+id/timer">
                </TextView>
                <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/stopbutton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/stopText"
                    android:id="@+id/stopButton"
                    android:visibility="gone">
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/startbutton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/startText"
                    android:id="@+id/startButton">
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/resetbutton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"                   
                    android:text="@string/resetText"
                    android:id="@+id/resetButton">
                    </Button>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout  !!!MESSED UP CODE. DON'T KNOW HOW TO SHOW DOTS USING XML
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                 <View class="com.category.tap.DrawV"
                android:id="@+id/dotpic"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

If anyone needs more information, let me know.

Comment: try using `ctrl+k` to highlight code, as it is hard to read

Comment: How do I make something a View?  Do I need to change View or RelativeLayout or FrameLayout or all of the above?

Comment: use a RelativeLayout !

Comment: I have tried all of these options with no success.  Could someone give the actual code, so I can see for sure what I'm doing wrong?  I hate to sound lazy, but I'm at wit's send.

Comment: Your code/text formatting is an abomination to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 9):

Inside the `XML` file, declare both `Views` inside a `FrameLayout`, the one that should be in top of the other, should be declared last.

To declare a custom created view, use the following format:

```
<com.mypackage.MyCustomView
    android:layout_width=......
```

Comment: <com.category.tap.DrawV
android:id="@+id/dotpic"     android:layout_width="fill_parent"     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 gives me an error:  "The application TAP (proess com.category.tap) has stopped unexpectedly.  Please try again.

Comment: This is the errors when I use com...Otherwise the errors are: [2014-06-11 16:40:31 - TAP] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.category.tap/.GameActivity }
[2014-06-11 16:40:31 - TAP] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stack both of your layouts, first add them to a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).

Comment: What exactly do you use?  Do you put just <FrameLayout> outside each Layout?  Do you use it twice or once?

Comment: You use it once and put your other two layouts in it

Comment: Hey @MrEngineer13! that' a pretty good answer and a pretty cute profile pic :)

Answer (score 0):

For stacking views relaivelayout or framelayout can be used. These layout support z-index placement so the views can overlap eachother. You cannot have two setcontentview in same activity. To show a dot on screen you can do this too:

```
<View android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

Comment: Really?  I can only use one layout for everything?  Knowing for sure would serve me a lot of trouble.

Comment: If I post this elsewhere a little cleaner, will I get into trouble?

Comment: @user963070 you are encouraged to post it and you will not be in any sort of trouble lol however it is a good practice(not required) to mention the original source.